# How could I read a file in fs without the file extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.js-fs

How could I read a file in FS without having to put the file extension.

e.x: `fs.readFile(../hello**.png(without this file extension?**`

Tried this and this returned not found.

Comment: You cannot. Its part of the file name.

Comment: This seems to be a an XY question? What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What if you had hello.jpg?

Answer (score 2):

As @tkausl said, it is not possible because without the file extension, the operating system doesn't know the type of file, and can't read it.

You could try to use the `glob` module to find a file using a certain pattern.

Here is an example:

```
const glob = require('glob');
const fs = require('fs');

glob('../hello.*', (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    fs.readFile(files[0], (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(data);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('File not found');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Saw an answer using the **glob** npm package. And it is possible to use, but not necessary. So, why not stick to the built-in modules of Node.js? No need to install any extra packages...

The code would look like this:

```
const { readdirSync, readFileSync } = require('fs');
const { dirname, parse } = require('path');

function readFileGuessExtension(pathWithNoExtension) {
  try {
    let files = readdirSync(dirname(pathWithNoExtension));
    let name = parse(pathWithNoExtension).base;
    let found = files.find(x => x.indexOf(name) === 0);
    return readFileSync(dirname(pathWithNoExtension) + '/' + found, 'utf-8');
  }
  catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(readFileGuessExtension('somePathWithoutFileExtension'));
```